# Where to find an interactive PDF or HTML version of the tex.web documentation?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, documentation, web, cweb

I have problems with the memory management of an eTeX created with Jim Fowler's TeX's pascal to javascript compiler [web2js](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js) as soon as I want to dump the eTeX format `etex.src` with more than only "USenglish" in the `language.def`.

I found this §13 in **tex.pdf** generated by `pdftex tex.tex`  which can help to solve my problem, but here I am referred to over 100 other sections.

> 13. In case somebody has inadvertently made bad settings of the “constants,” TEX checks them using a global variable called bad . This
>       is the ﬁrst of many sections of TEX where global variables are deﬁned.
>       h Global variables 13 i ≡ bad : integer ; { is some “constant” wrong?
>       } See also sections 20, 26, 30, 32, 39, 50, 54, 73, 76, 79, 96, 104,
>       115, 116, 117, 118, 124, 165, 173, 181, 213, 246, 253, 256, 271, 286,
>       297, 301, 304, 305, 308, 309, 310, 333, 361, 382, 387, 388, 410, 438,
>       447, 480, 489, 493, 512, 513, 520, 527, 532, 539, 549, 550, 555, 592,
>       595, 605, 616, 646, 647, 661, 684, 719, 724, 764, 770, 814, 821, 823,
>       825, 828, 833, 839, 847, 872, 892, 900, 905, 907, 921, 926, 943, 947,
>       950, 971, 980, 982, 989, 1032, 1074, 1266, 1281, 1299, 1305, 1331,
>       1342, and 1345. This code is used in section 4.

It is very time-consuming to work through this list of references.

Is this documentation also available with interactive links - incl. back button - instead of just plain textual links? As an interactive PDF or in an HTML version?

**The important thing is the interactivity of the links.**

A follow up question: [How to change table of content layout for a pdf document created from a web source file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501848/how-to-change-table-of-content-layout-in-package-texdoc)

Comment: which pdf viewer do you use? Many support jumping back to the previous position

Comment: @sive I use PDF-XChange Viewer and just found the back button. Good tip. The forward linking of the sections still remains.

Comment: Also, looking at all these “See also” sections won't help you at all (as you'll simply get a list of all globals in the TeX program, which is very large); instead you ought to look under “bad” (the variable you care about) in the [index](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=482) — it is defined in section 13 (the one you're seeing) and referred to again in 14 (initialized to 0), 111, 290, 522, 1249 (all the ways in which it can be set — these 4 sections are what you care about), then finally in 1332 (the value is checked).

Comment: ShreevatsaR  My "real" problem results from section 111 `if fontmax > fontbase + 256 then bad ← 16;`. I'm currently writing a node.js script which executes a complete run of: tie, tangle, compile and initex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not from “The TeXbook”, but is rather the typeset version of the WEB source for TeX (the program).

This is available in the TeX Live distribution (possibly also with MiKTeX) as a hyperlinked PDF file, with `texdoc tex` or from [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf).

[image]

The red numbers are hyperlinks pointing to the corresponding module or section.

If I hover on a link I get the exact location (Skim, in this case, shows a preview of the linked text)

[image]

Comment: I didn't know texdoc yet. What's this weird table of contents? Is it possible to list all sections (with description and clickable) instead or additionally?

Comment: Why are 16 sections between section 1 and 17 skipped from the table of contents? Is it fixable?

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi The table of contents lists the parts, which are made of sections (with continuous numbering through parts). Since the source is freely available, you can modify the way the TOC is produced. However, just the first section has a title (that you see as the part title), so listing sections in the TOC doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: But in the the same layout as **`See also sections`** it would be very useful.