# How to change table of content layout for a pdf document created from a web source file?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, tex-core, latex-misc

```
weave tex.web     
pdftex tex.tex
```

generates a pdf as follows with a table of content and a document body:

[image: section 13 in pdf]

Pay attention: The table of content is below the document!

[image: table of content]

I want the table of content listing all sections between two entries in the TOC in the same layout as in ***"See also sections"*** in section 13 of the body, everything indented left and right. In this way you can navigate directly from the table of contents to all sections.

How to do this?

This is a follow up question to [Where to find an interactive PDF or HTML version of the tex.web documentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501817/where-to-find-an-interactive-pdf-or-html-version-of-the-tex-web-documentation)

And here's a follow up question [How to add a second table of content to tex.pdf with a LaTeX package by using the contents.tex generated by pdfwebmac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502044/how-to-add-a-second-table-of-content-to-tex-pdf-with-a-latex-package-by-using) to this question.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `texdoc` _per se_: it just opens the approprite PDF

Comment: `texdoc` just calls a PDF viewer. The operation should be on the `weave` side, by changing the input macro file. Not something I'd like to study, sorry.

Comment: As sections other than the major ones (the ones that show up in the table of contents above) don't have any names, what would it mean to list them? You'll just have sections named “2”, “3”, ... “16”, and so on in the table of contents; what use is that?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That they are clickable! I will usually open this document with a question about a particular section that I want to navigate to quickly.

Comment: There's something weird in the code example at the top of your question: `texdoc tex` will always open a fixed documentation file that was installed by your distribution (e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf`). I think/hope you meant to write `weave tex.web` followed by `pdftex tex.tex` followed by opening the generated `tex.pdf` (and not using texdoc anymore).

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi the table of contents should be at the end of the pdf by default

Comment: Note that for a clickable table of contents you should use `pdfwebmac`, not `webmac` -- as mentioned in the first paragraph of @texdr.aft's answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I took texdoc completely out of the question. It only caused confusion.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I created a follow up question. [How to add a second table of content to tex.pdf with a LaTeX package by using the contents.tex generated by pdfwebmac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502044/how-to-add-a-second-table-of-content-to-tex-pdf-with-a-latex-package-by-using-th). I hope to have presented everything correctly: weave, tex.tex, webmac, pdfwebmac, pdftex, texdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg said, you have to modify the `WEB` macro file. For output with hyperlinks, this file is called `pdfwebmac.tex`. (For use with non-pdfTeX, the file is called `webmac.tex`.)

The changes concern the output to the `CONTENTS.tex` file. This output is produced by the `\Z` macro, which is called every time a starred section is created with `\N`; the definition of `\N` is:

```
\outer\def\N#1.#2.{\MN#1.\vfil\eject % beginning of starred section
  \def\rhead{\uppercase{\ignorespaces#2}} % define running headline
  \message{*\modno} % progress report
  \edef\next{\write\cont{\Z{#2}{\modno}{\the\pageno}}}\next % to contents file
  \ifon\startsection{\bf\ignorespaces#2.\quad}\ignorespaces}
```

The important part is `...\write\cont{\Z{#2}{\modno}{\the\pageno}}}`. Just copy this line into the definition for `\M`, which is used for unstarred sections (changing `\Z{#2}` into `\Z{#1}` to avoid parameter mismatching):

```
\outer\def\M#1.{\MN#1.\ifon\vfil\penalty-100\vfilneg % beginning of section
  \edef\next{\write\cont{\Z{#1}{\modno}{\the\pageno}}}\next % to contents file
  \vskip12ptminus3pt\startsection\ignorespaces}
```

If you're unhappy with the formatting then you could define another command instead of `\Z` to use with unstarred modules, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I created a follow up question. First of all only 2nd TOC from bottom to top: [How to add a second table of content to tex.pdf with a LaTeX package by using the contents.tex generated by pdfwebmac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502044/how-to-add-a-second-table-of-content-to-tex-pdf-with-a-latex-package-by-using-th)