# How to add a second table of content to "tex.pdf" with a LaTeX package by using the "contents.tex" generated by 'pdfwebmac'?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, tex-core, web

This is a follow up question to [How to change table of content layout for a pdf document created from a web source file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501848/how-to-change-table-of-content-layout-for-a-pdf-document-created-from-a-web-sour)

I input the following commands:

```
weave tex.web     
pdftex tex.tex
```

and create a PDF whose appearance depends on the macro file in the 1st line of **`tex.tex`** whose content is controlled by weave.

```
\input pdfwebmac
% This program is copyright (C) 1982 by D. E. Knuth; all rights are reserved.
```

`tex.tex` is generated by weave

Alternatively, the first line can also contain `\input webmac`.

In case of `pdfwebmac` we have an interactive PDF with hyperlinks in the sections and in the table of content which will be at the bottom of the PDF. (You can get a similar PDF with the command `texdoc tex`. But there's the table of content at the beginning of the document.)

The TOC is controlled by **`contents.tex`** which contains

```
\Z {\?1] Introduction}{1}{3}
\Z {\?2] The character set}{17}{10}
\Z {\?3] Input and output}{25}{13}
...
```

`contents.tex` is generated by a macro from pdfwebmac

- sequential numbering
- title of section
- number of section
- number of page

Can one now use this `contents.tex` to insert a 2nd TOC (with hyperlinks) at the beginning of the document? How to do this?

Could the generated PDF be read with the help of a more modern LaTex package (more modern than pdfwebmac) and extended with another table of contents after `contents.tex`?